# how to clear and select items programmatically

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm using https://ant.design/components/select/

How can I programmatically remove the selected items from `<Select>`?
**Note**: the `<Option>` is not a string value, but a Node.

Comment: Please provide some come you have tried

Comment: I'm trying to bind a state like <Select value={value_from_state}>, but it does not work. I'm new to antd, any idea how I can clear select items?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are using React Hooks, use the following:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Button, Select } from 'antd'

const { Option } = Select

// inside your component
const ComponentName = () => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState()

  // handler
  const clearSelected = () => {
    // this line will clear the select
    // when you click on the button
    setSelected(null)
  }

  // in the return value
  return (
    <>
      // ...
      // In the select element
      <Select style={{ width: 150 }} onChange={value => setSelected(value)} 
        value={selected}>
        <Option value="jack">Jack</Option>
        <Option value="lucy">Lucy</Option>
      </Select>
      <Button onClick={clearSelected}>Clear Selected</Button>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Readonly<SelectProps<SelectValue>>): Select<SelectValue>', gave the following error.
    Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | number | ReactText[] | LabeledValue | LabeledValue[] | undefined'.

Comment: also setting it to undefined instead of null doesn't work either

Answer (score 7):

Just set value to null.
e.g.

```
<Select value={null} />
```

Comment: how to access <Select> component?

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
    class Banana extends React.Component {
          constructor() {
            super();
            this.state = {
        selected: []
};

            this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
            this.clearSelected = this.clearSelected.bind(this);
          }

          handleChange(value) {
            this.setState({ selected: value });
          }

          clearSelected() {
            this.setState({ selected: []});
          }

          render() {
            return (
              <div>
                <Select value={this.state.selected} style={{ width: 120 }} onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="Select option">
                  <Option value="jack">Jack</Option>
                  <Option value="lucy">Lucy</Option>
                  <Option value="disabled" disabled>Disabled</Option>
                  <Option value="Yiminghe">yiminghe</Option>
                </Select>
                <Button onClick={this.clearSelected}>clear selected</Button>
              </div>
            );
          }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks! with this way keep the `placeholder` prop.

Answer (score 2):

Assigning the value of Select to state should work. Try something like this:

```
class Banana extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.clearSelected = this.clearSelected.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(value) {
    this.setState({ selected: value });
  }

  clearSelected() {
    this.setState({ selected: null });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Select value={this.state.selected} style={{ width: 120 }} onChange={this.handleChange}>
          <Option value="jack">Jack</Option>
          <Option value="lucy">Lucy</Option>
          <Option value="disabled" disabled>Disabled</Option>
          <Option value="Yiminghe">yiminghe</Option>
        </Select>
        <Button onClick={this.clearSelected}>clear selected</Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NwYdEx?editors=0010

Comment: Thanks, Max. I'm using similar code with some differences:
1. The <Option> is not a string render. I'm rendering with <img><span> blabla
2. The <Select> value is not a string, so I'm using labelInValue={true}

But, I got warning:
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `value` supplied to `Select`, when you set `labelInValue` to `true`, `value` should in shape of `{ key: string, label?: string }`.

Answer (score 1):

Use undefined for the placeholder text to appear. It will not appear with null.

In this case, when selectValue variable is set to 0, null, undefined, false, the Select value is clearead.

```js
      <Select onChange={e => setSelected(e)} 
        value={selectValue || undefined}>
        <Option value="1">Apple</Option>
        <Option value="2">Orange</Option>
      </Select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using State. Code was taken from the library itself (*_this.onClearSelection* in **Select.js**).

```
class MySelection extends React.Component {
      constructor() {
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.clearSelected = this.clearSelection.bind(this);
      }

      handleChange(value) {
        this.setState({ selected: value });
      }

      clearSelection() {
        const _this = this.refs.mySelection.rcSelect;
        const props = _this.props;
        const state = _this.state;

        if (props.disabled) {
          return;
        }

        let inputValue = state.inputValue;
        let value = state.value;

        if (inputValue || value.length) {
          if (value.length) {
            _this.fireChange([]);
          }

          _this.setOpenState(false, {
            needFocus: true
          });

          if (inputValue) {
            _this.setInputValue("");
          }
        }
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <Select ref="mySelection" onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="Select option">
              <Option value="jack">Jack</Option>
              <Option value="lucy">Lucy</Option>
            </Select>
            <Button onClick={this.clearSelection}>clear selected</Button>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In antd, In Class Component, Using Ref, Clear or reset select list value or form item value

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64077769/11844605

Answer (score 0):

The question is about antd. All the answers below are normal react way to clear select.

But `antd` is much powerful and offers `useForm` ref which can be used to clear form values.

You need to wrap your select within `Form.Item` and give it a name.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Button, Select } from 'antd'

const { Option } = Select

const ComponentName = () => {

  // using this for the form reference
  const [form] = Form.useForm();

  // handler
  const clearSelected = () => {
  // mySelect is the Form.Item name select below in the html  
    form.setFieldValue('mySelect', undefined);
  }

  const onFinish = (values) => {
    console.log(values)
  }

  // in the return value
  return (
    <>
      <Form form={form} initialValues={{mySelect: 'jack'}} onFinish={onFinish}>
        <Form.Item name="mySelect">
          <Select>
            <Option value="jack">Jack</Option>
            <Option value="lucy">Lucy</Option>
          </Select>
        </Form.Item>

        <Button onClick={clearSelected}>Clear Selected</Button>

        <Form.Item>
          <Button htmlType="submit" type="primary" loading={loading}>
             Submit
          </Button>
        </Form.Item>
      </Form>
    </>
  )
}
```

Also with antd, you don't need to hold any state variables for holding the form values. Just wrap all antd Components within `Form.Item` and give a name. When the form is submitted, you'll get all the name-value pairs in the `onFinish` callback.

Answer (score 0):

> **TL;DR** You only need `onClear` and `allowClear` props from Antd Select. NO need for (complicated) workaround.

For `antd:  4.6.0` and up, there is a `onClear` prop in the select component. We will also use `allowClear` prop to only show the clear button when a value is present (`true` will be enough but change according to your usage).

According to the [Documentation](https://ant.design/components/select/)

> **allowClear**:   Show clear button

> **onClear**:  Called when clear

```
import React from "react";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import { Select } from "antd";

const { Option } = Select;

const handleChange = (value) => {
  // NOTE: Handle null checking when value is
  // undefined when option is cleared
  console.log(`selected ${value}`);
};

const handleClear = () => {
  console.log("cleared value");
};

const App = () => (
  <>
    <Select
      placeholder="No Option Selected"
      defaultValue={"lucy"}
      onChange={handleChange}
      onClear={handleClear} // Add this
      allowClear={true} // Add this
    >
      <Option value="jack">Jack</Option>
      <Option value="lucy">Lucy</Option>
      <Option value="Yiminghe">yiminghe</Option>
    </Select>
  </>
);

export default App;
```

If you want to try it out, here is the [codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-usage-antd-4-23-5-forked-t6hy86?file=%2Fdemo.js)