# Show placeholder instead of selected value

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using [Ant Design `<Select>`](https://ant.design/components/select/) component. What is happening is that when first time the component is loaded it shows placeholder but when I select some value and then again trying to change, then at the place of placeholder selected value is showing. That is correct as per default behavior. But I would like to show placeholder every time the select box is clicked.

Please check the [working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-feather-jonv5).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, it is default behavior in ant design to show selected value as placeholder and there is no such option to change that behavior.

However you can achieve it making changes to css like this.

```
.ant-select.ant-select-open.ant-select-focused.ant-select-enabled
  .ant-select-selection.ant-select-selection--single
  .ant-select-selection__rendered
  .ant-select-selection-selected-value {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.ant-select.ant-select-open.ant-select-focused.ant-select-enabled
  .ant-select-selection.ant-select-selection--single
  .ant-select-selection__rendered
  .ant-select-selection-selected-value::before {
  visibility: visible;
  content: "Select a Person";
}
```

Here is working sample link
https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-hugle-49ify

Comment: Thanks. This is working. The only problem is when I have many fields then I have to write one class of each field.

Answer (score 1):

Showing the placeholder in a select input as an option is not `Ant Design` style. What you really want is to be able to deselect (clear) after selecting.

In `Ant Design`'s `select` component it is done using a `clear button` which will be shown if you pass the `allowClear` option.

```
<Select
  allowClear
  // ...
</Select>
```

After clearing the placeholder is shown again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, by clicking on clear I can do that but I am looking for automatic process. Like when I click on select automatically clear.

Comment: Are you talking about this?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47415280/how-to-clear-antd-select-items-programmatically

Comment: NO. I do not want to remove selected values. I just want to show placeholder every time select box is clicked.

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: Tell the client that it is not how it is done in Ant Design )

Answer (score 0):

Use an empty array for the **value** prop:

```
<Select
  value={[]}
  // ...
</Select>
```

I had a similar problem, this worked for me.