# Clear content in select box when first select option changed - reactJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, reactjs

I am new to `ReactJS`. I have used `AntJS` select in my `ReactJS` project. I have two `select` in `HTML`. When the `first select` is selected, its relative dropdown will be loaded in the `second select`.

UI View:
[image]

When the user chooses the option in the `first select`, the `second select` will load its contents.

It was working great. Now my issue was " When I choose an option in `second select`, it is there in the `second select box`. But When I changed the option in the `first select`, the already chosen option in the `second select` is still there, but the drop-down content in the `second select` has changed.

My Issue in UI View:
[image]
How to clear the selected content in the `second select` box when the `first select` option has changed". I have tried so far. I don't how to make it possible. Help me with some solutions.

Code:

```
WAAccountNameChange(value){  
        this.setState({selectedValue:"", waWebsiteList: this.state.waAccountWebsiteList[value] }) 
    }
```

First Select:

```
<Select  " onChange= {(value) => { this.WAAccountNameChange(value)}} >
    {this.state.waAccountList.map((item, index) => <Select.Option value={item} key={index}>{item}</Select.Option>)}
</Select>
```

Second Select:

```
<Select  defaultValue={this.state.selectedValue}  onChange= {(value) => { this.setState({ selectedValue: value })} } >
    {this.state.waWebsiteList.map((item, index) => <Select.Option value={item} key={index}>{item}</Select.Option>)}
</Select>
```

Comment: try adding a defaultValue attribute to the second Select, and set it to the selectedValue state, and reset the selected value when the first Select is changed

Comment: I tried that way. I doesn't get worked..the value in the `second select` is still there

Comment: Reset the selected value when the first Select is changed

Comment: in the onChange of the first select, set the selectedValue to empty

Comment: yes, i have set there, `this.setState({selectedValue:""})`. but still it shows

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47415280/how-to-clear-antd-select-items-programmatically 

have a look at this

Comment: Could you please share your base code e.g. on sandbox

Answer (score 0):

On the change of first select menu clear the value of second select box. If you retrieve data from API than clear state on API success.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).